# Import csv to database delimeter issues

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

The 3rd column in some row holds semi colon: `test 1; test 2; test 3`

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` VALUES ('21', 'test data', 'test 1; test 2; test 3', '', 'Other', 'test data', 'Free                ', '')
```

What should be the setting for delimeter options in phpmyadmin to import in this situation?

My `test.csv` file is saved in the `comma(,)` separated format

Tried with column separated with: `\t`

Throws error as: `Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What code are you using to read the file?  You appear to be confusing a table with a file.  There is no issue reading semicolons in a *comma*-delimited file.

Comment: I am trying to make you understand that am importing my `test.csv` file to `test_table`. Facing error as such as stated above

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring insert record error, solved my problem without any delimeter changes.